# Двойной слэш в URL

Tags: laravel

Есть роут

```
Route::get('/{slug}', 'CategoryController@view')->name('view.category');
```

Контроллер

```
public function view($slug) {
  $category = Category::where('slug', $slug)->first();
  return view('category', [
    'category' => $category
  ]);
}
```

Если перейти по ссылки `site.ru/name` - все хорошо работает

Если перейти по ссылки `site.ru/luboy-tekst/name` - Ошибка 404

Если перейти по ссылке `site.ru//luboy-tekst/name` - именно с двумя слэшами, то он открывает категорию 
Как от этого дубля избавиться, либо если он по такой ссылке находит, делать редирект(`site.ru//luboy-tekst/name` => `site.ru/name`)

Answer (score 0):

В контроллере проверить чтоб слуг был не нулл и выкинуть на 404

`site.ru/{null}/luboy-tekst/name` - вот почему у вас проходит

А еще можно в настройках сервера подменять `//` на `/`

Comment: Добавил проверку на `$slug`, страница все равно открывается. Если выводит `echo $slug` при двойном слэше `site.ru//luboy-tekst/name`, он выводит `name`

Comment: Странное поведение. А в мидлварях никакой логики по поводу слуга нет?

Comment: @Andrey_Ivasko Нет, нету